# Evaluate the surface integral of sphere above a plane.

Tags: calculus

> To find: Evaluate the surface integral$\iint_\sigma(x^2+y^2\, dS)$ where $\sigma$ is the portion of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ above the plane $z=1$
>   $$x^2+y^2=3, z=1$$
>   $$\, dS: z=(4-x^2-y^2)^\frac{1}{2}=f(x,y)$$

$$I=\iint_D(x^2+y^2)(1+f_x^2+f_y^2)^\frac{1}{2}\, dA$$

$$f_x=\frac{1}{\sqrt2u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}, u=1-x^2-y^2$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt u}=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}$$

> I am advised to change to polar coordinates to proceed further:

$$0\le r \le \sqrt{3}, 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$$

but where to from here?

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$

$$x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually start out by writing down the position vector along the surface in terms of the coordinates that parameterize the surface. So along the surface,
$$\vec r=\langle x,y,z\rangle=\langle r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,\sqrt{4-r^2}\rangle$$
Then we can find the total differential along the surface,
$$d\vec r=\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta,-\frac r{4-r^2}\rangle\,dr+\langle-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,0\rangle\,d\theta$$
Then, by taking the cross product of the partial derivative vectors we can get the vector areal element.
$$\begin{align}d^2\vec A&=\pm\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta,-\frac r{4-r^2}\rangle\,dr\times\langle-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,0\rangle\,d\theta\\
&=\pm\langle\frac {r^2\cos\theta}{\sqrt{4-r^2}},\frac {r^2\sin\theta}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}r\rangle\,dr\,d\theta\end{align}$$
Then we get the scalar areal element,
$$d^2A=\left|\left|d^2\vec A\right|\right|=\sqrt{\frac{r^4}{4-r^2}+r^2}\,dr\,d\theta=\sqrt{\frac{4r^2}{4-r^2}}\,dr\,d\theta=\frac{2r}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}\,dr\,d\theta$$
When $z=1=\sqrt{4-r^2}$, $r=\sqrt3$, so
$$\begin{align}\int f(x,y)d^2A&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt3}r^2\frac{2r}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}\,dr\,d\theta=2\pi\int_4^1(4-u)\frac{(-du)}{u^{1/2}}\\
&=2\pi\int_1^4\left[4u^{-1/2}-u^{1/2}\right]du=2\pi\left[8u^{1/2}-\frac23u^{3/2}\right]_1^4\\
&=2\pi\left[\left(16-\frac{16}3\right)-\left(8-\frac{2}3\right)\right]=\frac{20\pi}3\end{align}$$
Where we have made the substitution $u=4-r^2$.